# Yii2 Krajee TreeViewInput widget , how to use multiple select?

Tags: php, yii2, treeviewitem

I have three tables like this :

```
objects (id , name , tags , ...)
tags (id , name , ...)
object_tags(id , objectID , tagID)
```

I used [krajee treeView input](http://demos.krajee.com/tree-manager-demo/tree-view-input) and in my "objects" form I have :

```
$form->field($model, 'tags')->
                 widget(\kartik\tree\TreeViewInput::className(),[
                   'name' => 'kvTreeInput',
                   'value' => 'false', // preselected values
                   'query' => Tags::find()->addOrderBy('root, lft')->name,
                   'headingOptions' => ['label' => 'تگ'],
                   'rootOptions' => ['label'=>'<i class="fa fa-building"></i>'],
                   'fontAwesome' => true,
                   'asDropdown' => true,
                   'multiple' => true,
                   'options' => ['disabled' => false]
              ]);
```

But I have no idea how should I write the codes in my controller or in my model!!!

Comment: How should I insert related rows in my "tags" table???!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your action you should iterate over the post result

This is just a brief suggestion  you must add the code  related  to your specific need

```
  public function actionYourAction()
  {
      $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

      if (!empty($post)){

          $postTags =  $post['tags'];
            foreach ($postASCCId as $key => $value) {

                  $modelNew = new YourModel();

                  $modelNew->tag = $value;

                  $modelNew->save();
          }
      }  
      .....
  }
```

Comment: Can I use this in my create action?

Comment: you should place the related  code where you need .. in create action  .. where you perform the save of the  model  you are creating  .. but also in update (previous remove of the old values)  ..